# Editing text from outside shoes app overlaps text

Tags: ruby, text, shoes, green-shoes

I am working on a ruby app that needs to update text on the GUI at unknown times. The process I am using overlaps the text with text from the previous edit.

class_text is the element I need to edit. I have about 8 different places in the program that could potentially change the text. Sometimes when the text is changed the previous text does not get removed and instead the text overlaps itself.

```
$class_text.text = "Nothing scheduled to take attendance at this time."
```

This project was started by people before me and this is my first experience with Ruby. Thank you for any info you can send my way!

Comment: You got to use `#replace` if you want to modify the widget.

Answer (score 0):

without more specific information I've just tested a bare minimum for a scenario similar to yours (using Red Shoes though) and this works:

```
Shoes.app do

@test_stack = stack do
@edit_box = edit_box
@edit_box.text = "first text"

@edit_text = para "second text"
end

button "change" do
  @edit_box.text = "first replacement"
  @edit_text.text = "second replacement"
end

end
```

You could also try clearing the element first.

hth
seba

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I graduated this Spring, and no longer work in the office (it was a student job for my college). However I will send this answer to my replacement and if it fixes the problem Ill mark this as the right answer.